# Help with finding N-point functions with some properties

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, greens-function

I'm a physicist and I'm  working in a problem in general relativity where I end up with N-point functions that have to satisfy equations like this

\begin{equation}
\Big[\nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu +V(x_1)\Big]G(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)
\end{equation}

where $\nabla_\mu$ is a covariant derivative acting on $x_1$, $V(x)$ is some potential, $G(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in this case is a 3-point function evaluated at three different points $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ and $f$ is a source. There might be some properties that we can ask for. For example, $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ might already be symmetric in the last two indices. I would even be interested in a partial result for the case where $f=0$. The 3-point function must satisfy

1. It must be symmetric in all arguments.
2. It must vanish when at least two pairs of points are time-like separated.

In physics, time-like separated  just means that using the metric tensor, the distance between them is less than zero (Which is possible in semi Riemannian manifolds such as spacetime in General Relaivity).

**My question is: Are there any sources or literature about building these sort of generalized Green's functions with such properties?**

Any tip, help or advice in the right direction will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Here $x,x',x''$ are three different points, not point, first and second derivative? Certain formulations would not make sense for the second case, but the use of the primes for things other than derivatives is rare.

Comment: Oh yes I'm just labelling three different points! It's a common notation in physics but I understand in mathematics can mean something else! How should I label them? $x_1$ $x_2$ and $x_3$ might be better

Comment: There is no need to change notation, just mention the way it is to be interpreted. There might be a reason, like reducing the number of index ranges in the formula, or using different notation for different roles,...

Comment: If I read it correctly, then $x_2$ and $x_3$ appear only as parameters in the PDE. For 1. you can find a solution and then symmetrize over the arguments

Comment: I understand that the first condition is a bit more trivial, but the second condition is what makes the problem significantly more difficult!

Comment: Condition 2 is basically a boundary condition.  But please explain what you mean by "at least 2 pairs of points" when you have only 3 points?

Comment: That means that i should vanish if the pairs ($x_1$,$x_2$) and ($x_1$,$x_3$) are timelike or if the pairs ($x_1$, $x_2$) and ($x_2$, $x_3$) are timelike or if the pairs ($x_1$, $x_3$) and ($x_2$, $x_3$) are timelike

Comment: So having 2 pairs timelike does not imply the 3rd pair time like as well?

Comment: maybe you can use an analog of the Slater determinant to enforce the pairwise constraints.

Comment: @user619894 nope. You could have points $x_1$ and $x_2$ be at the same time slice but separated by, say, one meter. Point $x_3$ could be spatially half a meter from $x_1$ and $x_3$, right between them, but at a time way into the future. Then $x_3$ would be causally in the future of both $x_1$ and $x_2$ (Hence both pairs 13 and 23 are timelike) but the pair  12 is spacelike.

Comment: @user619894 Interesting! How would a slater determinant help with the spacetime constraints? I thought it only helped with antisymmetry under exchange of positions.

Comment: It is just a vague idea.If you are antisymmetric to exchange, then you are zero when two coordinates are at the same place. Now to extend this to being antisymmetric around lightlike lines or something